# Resources to learn just grammar

Tags: grammar, language-acquisition, germanic-languages

I'm interested in learning about the grammar of other languages (notably German, Russian, and Arabic), but I don't really want to *learn* to speak them. Only their grammar, syntax, morphology, etc., to the point where I would theoretically be able to translate as best as possible, word-for-word and have it in a different language. Are there any books or online resources that I can use to help me learn this?

Comment: Are you in fact asking "Are there reference grammars of German, Russian and Arabic"?

Comment: Not necessarily, but those are the languages with the most priority for me.

Comment: I'd just go to the library and pick up a standard grammar. I don't know about German, Russian or Arabic, but I think most major languages have de-facto standard grammars, like Li and Thompson for Mandarin, Matthews and Yip for Cantonese, Quirk et al. / Huddleston and Pullum for English, etc., and a good library would have those.

Comment: This is a very broad request. You should tell us more specifically what languages you are interested in so we can give you better recommendations, because as it currently is, any grammar for one of the ~7000 world's languages would qualify.